# How sign in automatically without asking login in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication, swrevealviewcontroller

I have different story board called Main, tabBar, home, map, etc. In tabBar storybard, I have used SWRevealViewController view and initiated as initially view. 
In main Storyboard only two are used namely sign in and sign up controller.

Here is my screenshot of tabBar storyBoard [image]

My question is when user logout and come back it automatically goes to home screen instead of going to sign in screen [This issue is due to SWRevealViewController is initial view controller].

Here code i tried : In sign view controller

In viewDidAppear check user available in firebase or not

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if API.User.CURRENT_USER != nil {
        // segue to the Tab Bar Controller
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInToTabBar", sender: nil)

    }
}
```

Sign in action:

```
  @IBAction func SignInButton(_ sender: Any) {

    view.endEditing(true)

    guard
        let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty,
        let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty
        else {

            self.showErrorAlert(message: "Username or email or passowrd should not be empty")
            return
    }
    // show the progress to the user
    ProgressHUD.show("Starting sign-in...", interaction: false)

    // use the signIn class method of the AuthService class
    AuthService.signIn(email: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, onSuccess: {
        // on success segue to the Tab Bar Controller
        API.User.observeCurrentUser { user in

            guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
                return
            }

            PrefsManager.sharedinstance.UIDfirebase = currentUser.uid
            PrefsManager.sharedinstance.username  = user.username!
            PrefsManager.sharedinstance.userEmail = user.email!
            PrefsManager.sharedinstance.imageURL  = user.profileImageURL!

            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Sucessfully signed in.")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInToTabBar", sender: nil)

        }

    }, onError: { errorString in
        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.showErrorAlert(message: errorString ?? "Server error")
    })

}
```

}

SWRevealViewController menu table i am listing menu like home, bookings, profile, logout :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! MenuTableViewCell

    cell.menuName.text = menuName[indexPath.row]
    cell.menuIcon.image = UIImage(named: menuImage[indexPath.row])


    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  //        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row

    if row == 0{

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)

        let obj = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: obj)
        navController.setViewControllers([obj], animated:true)
        navController.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        self.revealViewController().setFront(navController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)

    } else if row == 1{

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Bookings", bundle: nil)
        let obj = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BookingsViewController") as! BookingsViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: obj)
        navController.setViewControllers([obj], animated:true)
        self.revealViewController().setFront(navController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)


    } else if row == 2 {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
        let obj = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! profileViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: obj)
        navController.setViewControllers([obj], animated:true)
        self.revealViewController().setFront(navController, animated: true)
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)

    } else if row == 3 {
        print(indexPath)
        // Log out user from Firebase
        AuthService.signOut(onSuccess: {
            // Present the Sign In VC
    //                PrefsManager.sharedinstance.logoutprefences()
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let signInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signInViewController")
                        self.present(signInVC, animated: true)

  //                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signInVC, animated: true)

        }) { (errorMessage) in

            ProgressHUD.showError(errorMessage)

        }



    }


}
```

IN home view controller, checking user available or not:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if API.User.CURRENT_USER != nil {
        // segue to the Tab Bar Controller
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInToTabBar", sender: nil)

    }

    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

}
```

[image]

Comment: store userID and password somewhere if it not required login. do the login in background and get all details and move to tabbar

Comment: try this - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS

Comment: might be easier to just save login info in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 3):

When you signout from the app, you have to set your signIn view controller as the root view controller like this.

```
AuthService.signOut(onSuccess: {
       // Present the Sign In VC
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let signInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signInViewController") as! signInViewController
       let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:signInVC)
       let application = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
       application.window!.rootViewController = nav

}) { (errorMessage) in
        ProgressHUD.showError(errorMessage)
 }
```

Now in AppDelegate.swift file, in application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method, you have to check that user is nil or not.

```
if API.User.CURRENT_USER != nil {
       let mainNav = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
       let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "tabBar", bundle:nil)
       let sWRevealViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
       mainNav.pushViewController(sWRevealViewController, animated: false)
 }
```

**NOTE: Please add your storyboard Id and View controller name in identifier name and view controller name.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of navigation(performSegue), you have to change your RootViewController and set signInViewController as root VC.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let obj = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signInViewController") as! signInViewController
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = obj
```

Also, in your application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) you have to check for your user session

```
if API.User.CURRENT_USER != nil {
   //SET YOUR ROOT VIEW CONTROLLER HERE
}
```

You need set your root VC as, signInViewController or revealViewController(when the user exists)